# Auto completion issue in android-studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to make auto-completion of methods work in android-studio like it does in eclipse.
For example, if i have a method:

```
public void testMethod(String a, String b, int c) {}
```

and if i call it from eclipse and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, the auto completion of eclipse creates the full method with its parameters like this: `testMethod(a, b, c)`

but in android-studio, it is generated without its parameters: `testMethod();`

Same is the cases with generics type of methods or variables such as arraylists or hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

please also put information about your Android Studio version. It will be hard to guess without it.

My advise - first try with: Command look-up (autocomplete command name) <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

In Android studio you should have a view which shows you all mandatory parameters but as a prompt, not a predefined form of function.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html

Comment: There is no question (question mark) so I added this advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is another key Shortcut for Content Assistant. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

there are few changes in shortcut in Android Studio.

Check more commands here.
[Android Studio Shortcuts](http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-shortcuts-you-need-the-most/)